# Sql to pick n rows from each value of where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Example: select EMPLOYEENAME from EMPLOYEE where state in ('NY','CA','TX');

Is there any way to return 10 rows rows from each value in the where clause i.e 10 names from **each state**.

EDIT: I am using Oracle DB.

Comment: What RDMS? Many of them have window functions that make your task very easy

Comment: doing a union is not Scalable(no. of values in where clause)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 SELECT a.* FROM
 (
 select EMPLOYEENAME , 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY state ORDER BY EMPLOYEENAME) as rn
 from EMPLOYEE where state in ('NY','CA','TX')
 )a WHERE rn <=10;
```

Comment: Isnt depending on row_number an issue if there are inserts and updates happening while you are selecting data?

Comment: @javachecker The read will lock based on the transaction.  It is up to you to correctly implement locking if required.

Comment: +1 Might want to add **state** to the `SELECT` clause, but otherwise great.

Comment: @a1ex07 thanks for the answer. can you please shed some light on how partition is helping here.

Comment: @ javache: `Partition by state` ensures that for each state you will have rownumber starts with 1; thus, you can use `where rn <=10` in outer query which gives you what you want - up to 10 rows for each state.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *  
from  
(  
    select foo,bar,  
    row_number() over(partition by baz)  rn     
    from table
    group by foo,bar
)  
where rn <= 10
```

The use of analytic functions such as `row_number` allow partitioning based on some criteria.  This will essentially override the default `rownum` that oracle assigns.

If your concern is over concurrency, recall that a read will lock based on a transaction and will **not** block the inserts/updates.

Comment: that's not what OP wants. not total N row, but N rows from each group

Comment: but the thing here is just X rows from each value of State not as a whole